# iframe height not downsizing after longer page content

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, iframe-resizer

Using the David Bradshaw iFrame Resizer code for dynamic iframes.
Initially, it works and set's the appropriate height of the iframe to the content.
But when the user clicks a link to go to another page within the iframe, the height doesn't downsize if the content is less. If the content is more, it'll upsize just fine.

I've tried using the various attributes for heightCalculationMethod, all the same results. I look into the content of the iframe of the smaller pages and what I'm seeing is an html table(that doesn't have a defined height) then a huge gap underneath inside the body tag(which also doesn't have a defined height).
What am I missing here?

Here is my script..

```
<script>
iFrameResize({
    log:true,
    enablePublicMethod:true,
    heightCalculationMethod:'lowestElement'
});
</script>
```

Is it possible to just reset the iframe height?

Answer (score 2):

Quoted from https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

> IFrame not downsizing
>
> The most likely cause of this problem is having set the height of an
>   element to be 100% of the page somewhere in your CSS. This is normally
>   on the html or body elements, but it could be on any element in the
>   page. This can sometimes be got around by using the taggedElement
>   height calculation method and added a data-iframe-height attribute to
>   the element that you want to define the bottom position of the page.
>   You may find it useful to use position: relative on this element to
>   define a bottom margin or allow space for a floating footer.
>
> Not having a valid HTML document type in the iFrame can also sometimes
>   prevent downsizing. At it's most simplest this can be the following.

Comment: Would be valuable to see the site, do you have a link?

Comment: i do not because it's on a secure server with restricted access. what happens when working in a corporate environment. lol

Comment: I would suggest making a simple test case that you can share online.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just added a document type '<!DOCTYPE html>' at the beginning of my iFramed page and all get worked great! Finaly I've solved this problem after several days searching. ;-)))) It was so simple after all.

Answer (score 0):

Setting *heightCalculationMethod* to *'bodyScroll'* helped me in a same case:

go from a page inside iframe with **iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js** placed to another page without this script.

I use iFrame Resizer v3.5.8